# R CDM CHECK Possibly mis-spelled words in DESCRIPTION

Tags: r, cran

On my package, R CMD CHECK returns a NOTE about possibly mis-spelled words in DECRIPTION :

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE 
> Possibly mis-spelled words in DESCRIPTION: 
> Laverny (10:602) 
> Rullière (10:641)
```

Those two words are names of authors from a paper that i quote, the description field is as follows :

```
Description: Provides S4 classes and methods to fit several copula models: The classic empirical checkerboard copula and the empirical checkerboard copula with known margins, see Cuberos, Masiello and Maume-Deschamps (2019) <doi:10.1080/03610926.2019.1586936> are proposed. These two models allow to fit copulas in high dimension with a small number of observations, and they are always proper copulas. Some flexibility is added via a possibility to differentiate the checkerboard parameter by dimension. The last model consist of the implementation of the Copula Recursive Tree algorithm proposed by Laverny, Maume-Deschamps, Masiello and Rullière (2020) <arXiv:2005.02912>, including the localised dimension reduction, which fits a copula by recursive splitting of the copula domain. We also provide an efficient way of mixing copulas, allowing to bag the algorithm into a forest, and a generic way of measuring d-dimensional boxes with a copula.
```

The names of authors are not misspelled. How can i get rid of this note ?

Comment: You can get rid of the note by putting the names in single quotes, but this is inappropriate for people's names.  (It's appropriate for software package names.)  You should just ignore the note.  If you submit to CRAN, they'll ignore it.